# asp timespan validation with regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

In one of my models I'm using the following property :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the duration of the service")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Use format HH:MM only")]
public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
```

I used this regular expression to make sure that the duration`s format will be in HH:mm.

Every time that I tried to insert a value in that format I got the error message "Usage format HH:MM only". Once I removed the regular expression annotation I successfully saved an HH:MM (format string but I realized that it was saved in another format (HH:MM:SS). I tried to change the regular expression to the following annotation :

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Use format HH:MM:SS only")]
```

and now I can save duration in this format. It seems that when I try to save an HH:MM format it is automatically converted to HH:MM:SS and that's why it is failing in the annotation check.

How can I handle this issue? I don't want to enter the seconds of some flow, just the hours and the minutes.

Answer (score 3):

The [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs) calls the [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netcore-2.2) method of the `TimeSpan`, which results in the format you describe (i.e. including seconds). You could just create a customized `ValidationAttribute` based on the `RegularExpressionAttribute`, where you include the format `@"hh\:mm"` when calling `ToString` on the `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I used another solution

Answer (score 0):

I used the following annotation to solve the problem :

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
    [RegularExpression(@"((([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?)", ErrorMessage = "Time must be between 00:00 to 23:59")]
```